# Dynamically created fields in Gravity Form fails Honeypot validation on submission

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

My function is working as intended - the fields are dynamically added at the end of the form.

When honeypot is not turned on, the form submits saves to admin and sends the notification successfully.

When honeypot is turned on the frontend shows the success message as if it was submitted, but it never saves the entry or sends the notification. Upon checking the debug log, this is the output:

```
2023-01-24 8:40:21.672811 - DEBUG --> GF_Form_CRUD_Handler::cleanup(): Form meta => Array
(
    [title] => Job Application Form
    [description] => 
    [labelPlacement] => top_label
    [descriptionPlacement] => below
    [button] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [text] => Submit
            [imageUrl] => 
            [width] => auto
            [location] => bottom
            [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 12
        )

    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => GF_Field_Text Object
                (
                    [type] => text
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 1
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => First Name
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 1
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [inputs] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => hidden_label
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => 
                    [placeholder] => First Name*
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 6
                    [enablePasswordInput] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => ad4635a9
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [errors] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [checkboxLabel] => 
                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 
                )

            [1] => GF_Field_Text Object
                (
                    [type] => text
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 3
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => Last Name
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 1
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [inputs] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => hidden_label
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => 
                    [placeholder] => Last Name*
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 6
                    [enablePasswordInput] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => ad4635a9
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [errors] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [checkboxLabel] => 
                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 
                )

            [2] => GF_Field_Address Object
                (
                    [type] => address
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 4
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => Address
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 1
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [addressType] => us
                    [inputs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4.1
                                    [label] => Street Address
                                    [name] => 
                                    [autocompleteAttribute] => address-line1
                                    [customLabel] => Street Address*
                                    [placeholder] => Street Address*
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4.2
                                    [label] => Address Line 2
                                    [name] => 
                                    [autocompleteAttribute] => address-line2
                                    [isHidden] => 1
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4.3
                                    [label] => City
                                    [name] => 
                                    [autocompleteAttribute] => address-level2
                                    [customLabel] => City*
                                    [placeholder] => City*
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4.4
                                    [label] => State / Province
                                    [name] => 
                                    [autocompleteAttribute] => address-level1
                                    [customLabel] => State*
                                    [placeholder] => State*
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4.5
                                    [label] => ZIP / Postal Code
                                    [name] => 
                                    [autocompleteAttribute] => postal-code
                                    [customLabel] => Zip Code*
                                    [placeholder] => Zip Code*
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4.6
                                    [label] => Country
                                    [name] => 
                                    [autocompleteAttribute] => country-name
                                    [isHidden] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => hidden_label
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => hidden_label
                    [placeholder] => 
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [defaultCountry] => United States
                    [defaultProvince] => 
                    [copyValuesOptionLabel] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 
                    [defaultState] => 
                    [enableCopyValuesOption] => 
                    [copyValuesOptionDefault] => 
                    [copyValuesOptionField] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => 6e698c8d
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [checkboxLabel] => 
                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 
                )

            [3] => GF_Field_Phone Object
                (
                    [type] => phone
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 5
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => Phone
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 1
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [inputs] => 
                    [phoneFormat] => standard
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => tel
                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => hidden_label
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => 
                    [placeholder] => Phone*
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => 09f121e4
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [checkboxLabel] => 
                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 
                )

            [4] => GF_Field_Email Object
                (
                    [type] => email
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 6
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => Email
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 1
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [inputs] => 
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => email
                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => hidden_label
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => 
                    [placeholder] => Email*
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 
                    [emailConfirmEnabled] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => 838b9b0f
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [checkboxLabel] => 
                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 
                )

            [5] => GF_Field_FileUpload Object
                (
                    [type] => fileupload
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 7
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => Attach Resume
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 1
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [inputs] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => 
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => 
                    [placeholder] => 
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [maxFileSize] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [allowedExtensions] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [layoutGridColumnSpan] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => c60173e9
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [errors] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 
                )

            [6] => GF_Field_Section Object
                (
                    [type] => section
                    [_is_entry_detail:GF_Field:private] => 
                    [_context_properties:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_merge_tag_modifiers:GF_Field:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_supports_state_validation:protected] => 
                    [id] => 8
                    [formId] => 5
                    [label] => 
                    [adminLabel] => 
                    [isRequired] => 
                    [size] => large
                    [errorMessage] => 
                    [visibility] => visible
                    [inputs] => 
                    [displayOnly] => 1
                    [description] => 
                    [allowsPrepopulate] => 
                    [inputMask] => 
                    [inputMaskValue] => 
                    [inputMaskIsCustom] => 
                    [maxLength] => 
                    [inputType] => 
                    [labelPlacement] => 
                    [descriptionPlacement] => 
                    [subLabelPlacement] => 
                    [placeholder] => 
                    [cssClass] => 
                    [inputName] => 
                    [noDuplicates] => 
                    [defaultValue] => 
                    [enableAutocomplete] => 
                    [autocompleteAttribute] => 
                    [choices] => 
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [productField] => 
                    [enableEnhancedUI] => 0
                    [layoutGroupId] => a570ee61
                    [multipleFiles] => 
                    [maxFiles] => 
                    [calculationFormula] => 
                    [calculationRounding] => 
                    [enableCalculation] => 
                    [disableQuantity] => 
                    [displayAllCategories] => 
                    [useRichTextEditor] => 
                    [pageNumber] => 1
                    [fields] => 
                )

        )

    [version] => 2.6.9
    [id] => 5
    [markupVersion] => 2
    [nextFieldId] => 9
    [useCurrentUserAsAuthor] => 1
    [postContentTemplateEnabled] => 
    [postTitleTemplateEnabled] => 
    [postTitleTemplate] => 
    [postContentTemplate] => 
    [lastPageButton] => 
    [pagination] => 
    [firstPageCssClass] => 
    [subLabelPlacement] => below
    [requiredIndicator] => asterisk
    [customRequiredIndicator] => (Required)
    [cssClass] => 
    [saveButtonText] => Save and Continue Later
    [limitEntries] => 
    [limitEntriesCount] => 
    [limitEntriesPeriod] => 
    [limitEntriesMessage] => 
    [scheduleForm] => 
    [scheduleStart] => 
    [scheduleEnd] => 
    [schedulePendingMessage] => 
    [scheduleMessage] => 
    [requireLogin] => 
    [requireLoginMessage] => 
    [enableHoneypot] => 1
    [enableAnimation] => 1
    [validationSummary] => 
    [deprecated] => 
    [saveEnabled] => 
    [save] => Array
        (
            [enabled] => 
            [button] => Array
                (
                    [type] => link
                    [text] => Save and Continue Later
                )

        )

    [scheduleStartHour] => 
    [scheduleStartMinute] => 
    [scheduleStartAmpm] => 
    [scheduleEndHour] => 
    [scheduleEndMinute] => 
    [scheduleEndAmpm] => 
    [notifications] => Array
        (
            [63cf083e9b610] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 63cf083e9b610
                    [isActive] => 1
                    [to] => Trishaj@ruckusmarketing.com
                    [name] => Admin Notification
                    [event] => form_submission
                    [toType] => email
                    [subject] => New submission from {form_title}
                    [message] => {all_fields}
                    [service] => wordpress
                    [toEmail] => Trishaj@ruckusmarketing.com
                    [toField] => 
                    [routing] => 
                    [fromName] => {First Name:1}
                    [from] => {admin_email}
                    [replyTo] => {Email:6}
                    [bcc] => 
                    [disableAutoformat] => 
                    [enableAttachments] => 1
                    [notification_conditional_logic_object] => 
                    [notification_conditional_logic] => 0
                    [conditionalLogic] => 
                    [cc] => 
                )

        )

    [confirmations] => Array
        (
            [63cf083e9c269] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 63cf083e9c269
                    [name] => Default Confirmation
                    [isDefault] => 1
                    [type] => message
                    [message] => Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.
                    [url] => 
                    [pageId] => 
                    [queryString] => 
                )

        )

)
 
2023-01-24 8:40:21.673713 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::trim_form_meta_values(): Starting. 
2023-01-24 8:40:21.673815 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::trim_conditional_logic_values(): Starting. 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.517559 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Starting to process form (#5) submission. 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.519542 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Source page number: 1. Target page number: 0. 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.754956 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::get_temp_filename(): Uploaded filename is homeadvisor-color.svg and temporary filename is 63cfe00bb849d_input_7.svg 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.755081 - DEBUG --> GF_Field_FileUpload::validate(): Validating field input_7 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.769860 - DEBUG --> GF_Field_FileUpload::validate(): Validating file upload for homeadvisor-color.svg 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.769980 - DEBUG --> GF_Field_FileUpload::validate(): Validation complete. 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.770303 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): After validation. Is submission valid? Yes. 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.770384 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Uploading files... 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.770445 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::upload_files(): Upload path /nas/content/live/powerhrg2/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/5-51403278f6166fe42c507d417f729fc5 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.787142 - DEBUG --> GFFormsModel::get_temp_filename(): Uploaded filename is homeadvisor-color.svg and temporary filename is 63cfe00bb849d_input_7.svg 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.787241 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::upload_files(): Temp file info: Array
(
    [uploaded_filename] => homeadvisor-color.svg
    [temp_filename] => 63cfe00bb849d_input_7.svg
)
 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.808958 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::upload_files(): File uploaded successfully: homeadvisor-color.svg 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.809124 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::process_form(): Failed Honeypot validation. Displaying confirmation and aborting. 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.809190 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::handle_confirmation(): Preparing confirmation (#63cfe00bc58b8 - Default Confirmation). 
2023-01-24 8:41:31.809382 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::handle_confirmation(): Sending confirmation => <div id='gf_5' class='gform_anchor' tabindex='-1'></div><div id='gform_confirmation_wrapper_5' class='gform_confirmation_wrapper '><div id='gform_confirmation_message_5' class='gform_confirmation_message_5 gform_confirmation_message'>Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.</div></div>
```

Here's my function, and the filter's I'm hooking to:

```
//dynamically create new radio fields from get_job() array
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_5', 'add_screening_fields' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_5', 'add_screening_fields' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_5', 'add_screening_fields' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_5', 'add_screening_fields' );
function add_screening_fields($form) {
    // get new field ids
    $new_field_id = 0;
    foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
        if( $field->id > $new_field_id ) {
            $new_field_id = $field->id;
        }
    }
    $new_field_id++;

    // foreach 'question' inside get_job() array
    $job = get_job();
    foreach ($job['screening_questions'] as $question=>$q) {
        $answers = ['yes','no'];
        $items = array();
        foreach ( $answers as $answer ) {
            $items[] = array( 'value' => $answer, 'text' => $answer );
        }
        // Prepare GF field properties
        $props = array(
            'id'        => $new_field_id,
            'cssClass'  => 'gf_list_inline',
            'type'      => 'radio',
            'label'     => $q['question'],
            'choices'   => $items,
        );

        // Create new gravity forms field and add it to the form object
        $nf = GF_Fields::create( $props );

        // insert new fields into array at specific position (end of form)
        array_splice( $form['fields'], 7, 0, array($nf) );
        $new_field_id++;
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Am I not hooking to the right filters, or am I missing a validation step? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honeypot adds a hidden form field that must not be filled out by the user - so I would start by checking if your manipulated form still contains that field, or if it got lost somehow.

Comment: Are you using a form filler or auto filling the fields?

Comment: I think you might need to run validation on top of this. Either the `gform_field_validation` filter to validate a field or the `gform_validation` filter to validate the form. If you able to share your form's export json I can run it against your code in my environment and get a closer look at what's going on.